# CakePHP - Recuperar valor do option

Tags: php, cakephp

Olá! Estou consertando um website que peguei pronto e nele tem uma parte que o usuário seleciona um bairro em um `<option>`, porém, este `<option>` não está enviando a informação para o banco de dados.

Selecionando a cidade, aparece os bairros desta determinada cidade. Aqui está o arquivo view:

```php
echo $this->Form->input('cidade', array('label' => 'Cidade', 'empty' => 'Selecione uma cidade', 'options' => $Cidades));
echo $this->Form->input('bairro', array('label' => 'Bairro', 'empty' => 'Selecione o Bairro', 'options' => array()));
```

No controller, a função para add:

```php
public function add () {
    if (empty($this->request->data)); else {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        if ($data['Imovel']['opcoes']) $data['Imovel']['opcoes'] = implode(';', $data['Imovel']['opcoes']);
        $data['Imovel']['ativo'] = $data['Imovel']['ativoPeloAdm'] = 1;
        $data['Imovel']['creator'] = $data['Imovel']['modifier'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.Imobiliaria.id');
        if ($data['Imovel']['bairro']) {
            $bairro = $this->Cep->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $data['Imovel']['bairro'])));
            $data['Imovel']['bairroNome'] = $bairro['Cep']['bairro'];
        }

        if ($data['Imovel']['cidade']) {
            $cidade = $this->Cidade->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $data['Imovel']['cidade'])));
            $data['Imovel']['cidadeNome'] = $cidade['Cidade']['nome'];
        }

        $data['Imovel']['especificacao'] = $data['Imovel']['imovel'];
        if ($this->Imovel->save($data)) $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Ajax :

```php
    $('#ImovelCidade').change(function(e) {
    $('#ImovelBairro').html($('<option />').val('').text('Carregando...'));
    $.getJSON(
        "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'pegarBairros')) ?>", 
        { "cidade" : $(this).val() }, 
        function (data) { 
            $('#ImovelBairro').html($('<option />').val('').text('Selecione'));
            $.each(data, function (chave, valor) {
                $('#ImovelBairro').append($('<option />').val(chave).text(valor));
            } );
        }
    );
});
```

Função `pegarbairros` no controller:

```php
public function pegarBairros ($cidade = null) {
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $result = array();

    if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidade))) {
        $bairros = $this->Cep->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','bairro'), 'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']]),'group' => 'bairro'));
        sort($bairros);         

        foreach ($bairros as $id => $bairro) {
            if (!empty($bairro)) 
                $result[$id] = $bairro;
            else 
                $result[] = 'error';
            $this->set('data', $result);
        }
    }
}
```

estou tentando inserir um bairro, mas está retornando um Array

Comment: Parece estar faltando alguma coisa, normalmente nesse caso a consulta pelos bairros da cidade seria feita utilizando ajax. Tem certeza que está tudo aí? Não tem nenhum [tag:javascript] faltando?

Comment: Você ligou o nível 2 de debug no `core.php`?

Comment: @ErlonCharles , vou postar o js !

Answer (score 1):

Lendo seu código me parece que é um erro na formatação dos dados. Você precisa que seu [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) retorne um [json](/questions/tagged/json) assim você vai ter mais facilidade para manipular o retorno por [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) e gerar um [html](/questions/tagged/html) válido.

O que eu sugiro:

```
public function pegarBairros ($cidade = null) {
    $this->layout = 'json';
    $result = array();

    if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidade))) {
        $bairros = $this->Cep->find('list', array('fields' => array('id','bairro'), 'conditions' => array('cidade' => $this->cidade[$_REQUEST['cidade']]),'group' => 'bairro'));
        sort($bairros);         

        foreach ($bairros as $id => $bairro) {
            if (!empty($bairro)) {
                $result[$id] = $bairro;
            } else {
                $result[] = 'error';
            }
            $result = json_encode($result);
            $this->set('data', $result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eu troquei por este codigo e nao aparece nada, apenas carregando....

Comment: me mostre um exemplo do json que está sendo retornado

Comment: o json está retornando a posicao do item na lista...